# How to pass a variable from one function to another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

there are 2 functions(buy,close). at first buy() function will be executed via Button(tkinter GUI) and then later Close() function will be executed. so how to pass variable from buy function() to close() function.

```
def buy():
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'x-session-token': tokens
    }
    requestBody={
      "symbolName": "JSWSTEEL",
      "exchange": "NSE",
      "transactionType": "BUY",
      "orderType": "MKT",
      "quantity": "1",
      "disclosedQuantity": "1",
      "orderValidity": "DAY",
      "productType": "CO",
      "triggerPrice": "194.00"
    }
    r = requests.post('https://api.stocknote.com/order/placeOrderCO' ,data = json.dumps(requestBody), headers = headers)
    orderno = r.json().get("orderNumber")
    print (r.text)
    print (orderno)
    return orderno
a = Thread(target=buy)
a.start
def close():
    import requests
    headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'x-session-token': tokens
    }

    c = requests.delete('https://api.stocknote.com/order/exitCO', params={
      'orderNumber': orderno
    }, headers = headers)

    print(c.text)
cl = Thread(target=close)
cl.start
```

I need to pass Variable orderno from buy() function to close() function. im using tkinter GUI window to trigger each function, so buy() function will happen first later close() will be triggered.

Comment: Make a class and put your functions in it and you can use your variables in any function

Answer (score 0):

```
def open():
    """do stuff"""
    return orderno

def close(variable_you_want_to_pass):
    """do something here"""

orderno = open()
close(variable_you_want_to_pass = orderno)
```

`variable_you_want_to_pass` is now a local variable in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define your variable outside your buy() code ? In this case, your function buy() will modify a global variable, accessible from any function, including close().

Or you can make a class and just set your variable as a class attribute if you want a cleaner code.

Last solution, giving a parameter to your close :

```
def close (odn):
    orderno = odn
    ...
```

Make your buy() function return orderno
and then you just have to call close(buy())